# How to change quotations on a Word file

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

How to change quotations on a word file

For example

I want to automatically change from “Yamaha” to „Yamaha“ (Lithuanian quotations style)
There are a lot of words with the wrong quotation style.

Comment: What about your regional settings?

Comment: Lithuanian but I copied text from another file

Comment: Find and replace should work...

Comment: [Untested guess] How about disabling then re-enabling smart quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Using Word's find and replace tool, find [space]" and replace it with [space]„

[image]

The results in the below:

[image]

Comment: What if the quoted word was/is at the beginning of the paragraph for example "I" bought something?

Comment: Fill in "Yamaha" in Find what, and fill in „Yamaha“ in Replace with to avoid this.

Comment: @VikiJi that assumes all the words are Yahama, which I suspect they won't be.

Comment: Use a wildcard replace instead:  find ([ ^13])" and then replace with \1 and your desired quote mark.  That way you are searching for either a space or a paragraph mark before the opening quote, and replacing it with (either) the space or paragraph mark and then your new quote mark.